# OAuth2 Access token request missing code parameter - but I do have it included

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get the access/refresh tokens from google for use with the youtube api. My code is identical to the linked gist except for I've changed the function name of retrieve_tokens to get_tokens and I shortened the argument name https://gist.github.com/ymotongpoo/1907281

The error I first received was

line 53, in get_userinfo
    access_token = tokens['access_token']
KeyError: 'access_token'

And later found I was making an invalid request - the error said I was missing the code parameter in my token request which I clearly have. I am copying and pasting the auth code from the google redirect page.

I apologize if any of this is vague. I really appreciate the help.

```
def get_tokens(auth_code):
access_token_req = {
    "code": auth_code, #response says I'm missing this parameter
    "client_id": CLIENT_ID,
    "client_secret": CLIENT_SECRET,
    "redirect_uri": redirect_uri,
    "grant_type": "authorization_code"
    }

content_length=len(urlencode(access_token_req))
access_token_req['content-length'] = str(content_length)

r = requests.post(base_url + "token", data=access_token_req)
data = json.loads(r.text)
return data


def get_userinfo():
  global auth_code
  auth_code = get_auth_code()
  tokens = get_tokens(auth_code)
  access_token = tokens['access_token']
  auth_header = {"Authorization": "OAuth %s" % access_token}
  r = requests.get("https://www.google.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo",
                headers=auth_header)
  print r.text

get_userinfo()
```

Comment: did you provide valid client_id and client_secret?

Comment: try testing our your flows in the interactive [OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)